# Make Shared Object for Import Shared Object LabView

Tags: object, import, shared, labview

I must do a shared object that it will be used with "Import Shared Object" of LabView.
The initial file .cpp include other .cpp for use function.
How can I include other .o?
I must use, for example:

```
g++ name.o -shared -o libname.so
```

with the "-L" option?

```
g++ name.o -shared -o libname.so -L /usr/lib/name2.so
```

Is it right?

Thanks.